# Swift: can not invoke method with correct arguments?

Tags: swift, core-data

I am trying to find a count of entities which satisfy predicate. According to documentation and "header" files, this should work:

```
let fetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "FileRecord")
let ctx: NSManagedObjectContext = GetCtx()
let res = try ctx.count(for: fetch)
```

however I get compile error:

```
Cannot invoke 'count' with an argument list of type '(for: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>)'
```

however when I create the fetch request from FileRecord like this instead:

```
let fetch: NSFetchRequest<FileRecord> = FileRecord.fetchRequest()
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'NSFetchRequest<FileRecord>' to expected argument type 'NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>'
```

Please anyone got an idea what can be wrong? I am a decent C++ language lawyer but I am just a novice with Swift...

**EDIT: SOLVED**
My example above was wrong. In reality I had code functionally identical to:

```
let res: UInt64 = try ctx.count(for: fetch)
```

since count returns Int, the function did not match. The error message was not specific enough for me to see it immediately. Thanks to all who have tried to help :)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Is that your real code? Is `try` called in a do/catch context?

Comment: You need to put your code for `GetCtx()`, please update your question with code.

Comment: And `FileRecord` is not an `NSFetchRequest` its `NSManagedObject`, update the requested code above, so that i could help

Comment: Martin R yes, try is called in a do/catch context. Santos, GetCtx() is just a dummy function, in reality I simply have variable of type NSManagedObjectContext which I use for other purposes and which works normally. Santos, FileRecord is a name of entity in core data, and thus for it a Swift class is generated. It's static fetchRequest() method returns the actual fetch request. In general my problem is that although I match the signature of the method, it says that I can not invoke it. I have no clue what to do with that information.